# how to change a single digit number to string in MSSQL query

Tags: sql-server, date

```
SELECT 
a.AccountNumber, a.FirstName, a.LastName, a.Address, a.City, a.State, a.Zip, a.EmailAddress, 
a.PhoneNumber, a.LastUpdated, a.LastVisit, a.TotalSales, a.AccountOpened, a.CustomText4 as StoreCode, 
    CASE
        WHEN (a.CustomText1 = 'JAN') THEN '01' +'/'+a.CustomText2+'/'+a.CustomText3
        WHEN (a.CustomText1 = 'FEB') THEN '02' +'/'+a.CustomText2+'/'+a.CustomText3
        WHEN (a.CustomText1 = 'MAR') THEN '03' +'/'+a.CustomText2+'/'+a.CustomText3
        WHEN (a.CustomText1 = 'APR') THEN '04' +'/'+a.CustomText2+'/'+a.CustomText3
        WHEN (a.CustomText1 = 'MAY') THEN '05' +'/'+a.CustomText2+'/'+a.CustomText3
        WHEN (a.CustomText1 = 'JUN') THEN '06' +'/'+a.CustomText2+'/'+a.CustomText3
        WHEN (a.CustomText1 = 'JUL') THEN '07' +'/'+a.CustomText2+'/'+a.CustomText3
        WHEN (a.CustomText1 = 'AUG') THEN '08' +'/'+a.CustomText2+'/'+a.CustomText3
        WHEN (a.CustomText1 = 'SEP') THEN '09' +'/'+a.CustomText2+'/'+a.CustomText3
        WHEN (a.CustomText1 = 'OCT') THEN '10' +'/'+a.CustomText2+'/'+a.CustomText3
        WHEN (a.CustomText1 = 'NOV') THEN '11' +'/'+a.CustomText2+'/'+a.CustomText3
        WHEN (a.CustomText1 = 'DEC') THEN '12' +'/'+(select CONVERT(decimal(10,2),a.CustomText2))+'/'+a.CustomText3
    END AS DOB, GETDATE() as Extract_date
```

CustomText1 = JAN ~ DEC letter column so convert to numbers.
CustomText2 = is a Day with a number format.

I would like to convert this to two digit decimal. can anyone help me to to write the sql query?

Comment: you might be interested in ROUND

Comment: WHEN (a.CustomText1 = 'DEC') THEN '12' +'/'+(select ROUND(a.CustomeText2, decimal)+'/'+a.CustomText3

that didn't work. Could you tell me more info?

Comment: You might also want to look at [format()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_format) or [lpad()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Careful how you word your question.  You don't want a `decimal`, you want a string, to concatenate with your other string fragments.

This is what you want:

```
...RIGHT('0'+a.CustomText2, 2)...
```

If you actually cast it as a decimal, you will get errors trying to concatenate it with `'/'` and so on.

If you need the final outcome to be a `date` type, then CAST or CONVERT the whole CASE statement to that datatype.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I see. I need a string...

I have tried using WHEN (a.CustomText1 = 'DEC') THEN '12' +'/'+RIGHT('0'+a.CustomeText2,2)+'/'+a.CustomText3

No luck.....

Comment: Then there must be another error in another part of the query.  The part I gave in my answer is correct.   Please edit your question with the entire query you tried, and the exact error you got.

Comment: Sorry, your query is correct! it does work! Thank you so much!